# MySQL: Django .create followed by .get doesn't work without re-opening the shell

Tags: python, mysql, django, shell, innodb

```
>>> Anything.objects.create(title='test')
<Anything: test>
>>> Anything.objects.get(title='test')
DoesNotExist: Anything matching query does not exist.
>>> exit()
```

... reopen shell ...

```
>>> Anything.objects.get(title='test')
<Anything: test>
```

Super stumped here. Running Python 2.7.3; Django 1.5.4; MySQL 5.5 (innodb), Ubuntu 12.04.

Furthermore, opening the python shell first, and running an insert statement against mysql results in a similar situation where the record exists in the database, but the shell cannot find it.

Dumping the mysql log shows what you would expect: An insert statement, followed by a select; It seems to somehow be going against an outdated version of the database -- a version that seems to have been established at the beginning of the shell instance!

Running sequential insert and select statements directly against the database yields a similar result; where you cannot access the new information since the shell was instantiated.

Still chasing this down:

```
>>> t = TagManager.objects.create(title='test')
>>> t
<TagManager: test>
>>> t.id
1L
>>> TagManager.objects.get(title='test')
<TagManager: test>
>>> t2 = TagManager.objects.create(title='test2')
>>> TagManager.objects.get(title='test2')
DoesNotExist: TagManager matching query does not exist.
>>> t2.id
2L
>>> TagManager.objects.get(title='test2')
DoesNotExist: TagManager matching query does not exist.
>>> TagManager.objects.get(title='test')
<TagManager: test>
```

Exit shell...

```
>>> TagManager.objects.get(title='test2')
<TagManager: test2>
>>> TagManager.objects.create(title='test3')
<TagManager: test3>
>>> t.id
3L
>>> TagManager.objects.get(title='test3')
DoesNotExist: TagManager matching query does not exist.
>>> t = TagManager.objects.create(title='test4')
>>> t
<TagManager: test4>
>>> t.id
4L
>>> TagManager.objects.get(title='test4')
DoesNotExist: TagManager matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: What kind of python interpreter are you using?

Comment: python 2.7.3; django 1.5.4

Comment: _"Running sequential insert and select statements directly against the database"_ are you saying you see the same behavior from the `mysql>` prompt?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes, the mysql prompt works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was due to the REPEATABLE READ transaction isolation level that is the default behavior in MySQL

http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/db/transactions.html#using-a-high-isolation-level

Changing the transaction-isolation level in the mysql conf to be READ COMMITTED solves this.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that Anything.objects points to a Manager instance that is not behaving in the expected way (by saving the object in the create method)?

If not, then I expect your shell is running inside of a transaction that is not committing. You might see what a call to

```
django.db.transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

does after the call to create().

Comment: At this point Anything represents literally any object in the code, manager or no manager. Calling transaction.commit simply replies with an error reporting that the code is not under transaction management.
Updated question with more sql info.

Comment: I'm no MySQL expert, but it seems to me that the database could be "versioned" by transaction. django.db.transaction.commit_unless_managed() does something slightly different. Give that one a try. I would also paste some of the relevant MySQL log lines in your question.